# PHP: Strange behaviour with class extending abstract class and implementing an interface

Tags: php, interface, abstract-class

I have a class with the following structure.

```
abstract class ABS {}

interface INT {}

class SomeClass extends ABS implements INT
{
 //class implementation...
}
```

I'm working on my development environment with PHP 5.3
But when I uploaded to live (PHP 5.2.17) it just doesn't go to the end of declaration of the class SomeClass. Just stops there, no error, nothing. When i tested with some echo statements (in the begining of the class (before declaration) and in the end of the class(after declaration)) the echo statement that was in the end of the class declaration did not appear on the screen. When I remove either the extends or implements statement it reaches the end. Can you help me?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not migrating to 5.4 instead? Of better, could you describe why you can't update your server to >= your development PHP version?

Comment: I just switched to 5.3 in live and I'm waiting for the changes to take effect. I hope this will solve my problem.

Comment: Did you check the error logs? Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: update to 5.3 worked perfect. Thank you.